# pressing back button two times closes activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one strange problem. I have an app with two activity "login" and "normalDifficulty". When I am in login activity and I press back button it closes activity gracefully. But When I am in "normalDifficulty" and I press back button it restarts my "normalDifficulty". To close "normalDifficulty" activity I have to press back button twice. No matter what i do it always closes "normalDifficulty" after pressing twice. Please help me why it is happening and how to fix this. The below code i used to close the activity.

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                finish();
            }
        }).create().show();
}
```

I modified this by super.finish(), this.finish(), NormalDifficulty.finish(). But my activity always closes after pressing twice. Thank you.

Code where I am starting NormalDifficulty activity. this is happening in login activity where I decalared NormalDifficulty protected.

```
 enter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            boolean userNameStatus, emailStatus;
            userNameStatus = validate(userName.getText().toString(), USERNAME_PATTERN);
            emailStatus = validate(email.getText().toString(), EMAIL_PATTERN);
            if(userNameStatus && emailStatus) {
                if(rememberMe.isChecked()) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            PREFRENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    settings.edit().putString("name", userName.getText().toString())
                            .putString("pwd", email.getText().toString()).commit();
                } else {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            PREFRENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    settings.edit().clear().commit();
                }
            } else {
                showDialog("Invalid UserName or Email-ID");
                return true;
            }

            message = userName.getText().toString();
            startActivity(normalDiffculty);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please put the code where you open your normalDifficulty activity.

Comment: Try to change finsh () to super.onBackPressed ();

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29).

You can add `setCancelable(false)` like this.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setCancelable(false).
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()     {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            finish();
        }
    }).create().show();
```

This will prevent closing of dialog on clicking back after dialog is shown, and you can call activity's `finish()` in `onClick` of **YES**. And normal continuation in `onClick` of **NO**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No help. Since it restarts the app so dialog closes. I did some work around, I override onRestart() method and called finsish() inside it so when app restarts after pressing back button it closes the app. But doing so it generates exception and then closes the app. Thanks

Comment: I replace finsish() from system.exit(0) even though it does not exit by pressing back button one time. Still i have to press back button twice to close the app.

Comment: Tried with "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());" but even though my app restarts with different PID value. Still i have to press back button twice to close it. I am running app in emulator, could be because of that?

Comment: May be @user3687223 ry with device.

Comment: NO Still it gives same behaviour in emulator. I gave order for new andorid mobile.I will update you once my application will successfully execute in device.

Comment: I tried on real device but still it gives the same behavior. I have to press minimum two times back key to close the activity. Sometimes more than two times i need to press to close the activity. Any help?

Comment: Are you dealing with 1 activity or more than 1 activities in your applications? if more than 1, please finish prev activity while starting new one. @User3687223. I m having off today, so will try to help you on monday. :-)

Comment: Thank for the reply, I have three activity and I am closing every activity before going to next activity. I don't know how to fix this bug. will wait for your reply Thanks.

Comment: After long research finally I got the fix. The problem was that I was starting the activity inside Webview's ontouch listener. I don't know why but ontouch listener was firing randomly(twice or more than twice) when user touch the webview. So I declared one variable and did some work around so that my activity call only once. This problem was weird.

Comment: Oh great its fixed. Congrats :-) @user3687223